# Vim regex - hex character in replacement?

Tags: regex, vim, ascii

I want to do a global substitution over a range of lines in Vim:

```
:s/pattern/replacement/g
```

The 'pattern' is one character in a set, e.g. `[BEINS]` and the 'replacement' is a single character.  However, the wrinkle is that the single character is given to me as the 2 digit hex representation of the character in ASCII/Unicode.  Obviously I could look up a hex ASCII chart to see that for example `5F` is the underscore character then I could type `_` in the replacement part of the regex.

Is there a way to instead type the hex in the righthand side of the regex?

Things I tried that didn't work include:

```
:%s/[BEINS]/\x5F/g
:%s/[BEINS]/\\x5F/g
```

On my Linux workstation I can type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> followed by a hex code followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd> but I was wondering if there was a Vim-specific way to put the hex in the replacement part of the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>

```
:%s/[BEINS]/<ctrl>-vx5F/gc
```

Here's vim help page on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>:

> With <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> the decimal, octal or hexadecimal value of a character can be
>   entered directly.  This way you can enter any character, except a line  break
>   (, value 10).  There are five ways to enter the character value:

```
first char      mode         max nr of chars   max value
(none)          decimal            3            255
o or O          octal              3            377      (255)
x or X          hexadecimal        2            ff       (255)
u               hexadecimal        4            ffff     (65535)
U               hexadecimal        8            7fffffff (2147483647)
```

Comment: I tried using `%s/<C-V>x00/<C-V>x0a/g` to replace null bytes with new lines, however that didn't work. When trying to replace an A with `<C-V>x0a` it would replace it with a null byte.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
:%s/[BEINS]/\="\x5F"/gc
```

The magic:

```
1 - Use the expression register `\=`
2 - use double quotes
```